# Using Wildcard characters with . (period)

Tags: c#

I am trying to search files for strings such as "1.2.3.4" or "12.4.123.3"

I have been trying to use a .Contains("*.*.*.*"); but apparently from what I've found on the internet wildcards and periods don't go well together. I have tried using examples with escape characters and maybe I have just been doing it wrong, but I have had no luck.

Comment: Use Regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

> I have been trying to use a .Contains("*.*.*.*")

string.Contains looks literally for the text you supply between the quotes, and does not do pattern matching.

You can accomplish this using a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you are new to regular expressions, check out [RegExr](http://regexr.com/).  It's a nice, free online tool for learning and testing regular expressions.

If you wanted to match four groups of numbers with 1 to 3 digits in each group, the groups separated with period, the following would work

```
var matches = 
    Regex.IsMatch(candidate, 
                  "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a regex like:

```
string input = "12.4.123.3";

bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+");
```